# Avoiding CORS issues on web app importing JavaScript modules from other domains

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, interactjs

I am building a web application using NodeJS splitting the application into a back-end to handle database queries with MongoDB and a front end via a node  based webserver that uses interactjs with JavaScript compiled from TypeScript. Currently, I have it running on LocalHost.

For my front end, leaning on my desktop application development skills, I originally built an application modularly out of several JS modules in a serverless, on the local machine not even using local host, way. It constructs flowcharts drag and drop style implemented using typescript compiled to JS. I have now moved it into node. Most things seem to be working, but in one of my modules I am importing  interact.js to handle my drag and drop.

```
import interact from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/interactjs/index.js'
```

However, this seems to be causing CORS errors to be reported by my browser Firefox. I have done quite a bit of reading and understand what Cross Origin Resource Sharing is, and why problems occur. However,  I have yet to find a good source of information that helps me overcome my problem. A lot of the information seems to either describe what a CORS error is without offering a solution or provides examples mime types,or fetch commands which are not relevant to this (as far as I know).

If you are running a webapp that is at http://localhost:5000/myApp. How then can my code import external JavaScript modules without triggering the CORS errors?

What I am seeing many times over in the console of Firefox's is three likely related errors:

```
Loading module from “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/drag/plugin” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/drag/plugin. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/drag/plugin”.
```

I'm posting here out of desperation, as I have spent all day going around in circles and have not been able to find anything related to my problem on StackOverflow or elsewhere.

Comment: is it the import itself causing CORS errors, or what that library does that causes CORS errors - please show the errors you are getting

Comment: I think its the import itself.

Comment: in my experience, I've never seen importing trigger CORS errors, what CORS errors are you seeing

Comment: I'll add these errors to the posting..

Comment: That's not a CORS error, it's an invalid MIME type error.

Comment: Pointy, I've updated the question to include all three errors that repeat over and over in the console. I was thinking the CORS error was causing the mime type error, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Copy that URL into a new browser tab's URL bar and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: Pointy, thanks I did so and saw that it was JavaScript which is what I expected. What is the problem there that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/drag/plugin` is not javascript .... `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/drag/plugin.js` is, but that's not the URL the error is refering to

Comment: When I load `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/drag/plugin` into a tab I get a plain text message telling me "Couldn't find the requested file /drag/plugin in @interactjs/actions.".

Comment: Why is the .js being striped off? As you can see my import includes the .js?

Comment: Those bogus `import` lines are in `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@interactjs/actions/plugin.js` for reasons unknown. The problem is not yours, it's in the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Well done folks you were right, it was a wonky URL. I'd used that last Spring when I last worked on the project and it worked then. I can see the suggested URL at the interact.js website is now different.

Comment: I don't get why are you importing this the way your doing it? why not just installing with npm or yarn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@interactjs/interactjs` module isn't meant to be used over a CDN — you probably want [interactjs](https://github.com/taye/interact.js/tree/main/packages/interactjs) (without the leading `@`), because it looks like the namespaced versions are really meant for internal and build-time use. If you just need `drag`, you can get that from [their CDN](https://interactjs.io/docs/installation#cdn-streamlined): `import 'https://cdn.interactjs.io/v1.9.20/actions/drag/index.js'`.

Comment: That solved the issue. the URL was wonky pointing to changed resources. Thanks.

Comment: As another quick question, why does this not work as a named import:  import interact from 'https://cdn.interactjs.io/v1.9.20/actions/drag/index.js'   . Tells me it could not find the module or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: @AndrewS there's no export (neither a default nor a named export) in that build of the module. Looks to me like it's meant to be imported for its side effects (the `init` and `interact.use` calls).